# Dispatching to redux store from outside of a saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a saga that initialize an analytics provider, which lives completely outside of the redux context. However periodically Redux will push an updated auth token to this analytics provider.

(Yes i know the analytics code should probably live in the saga flow, but trust me I considered it and that refactor is not possible right now)

```
function* setupAnalyticsProvider(response: any): any {
     // get some global session data  
     setupAnalytics(data) 
}

export function* refreshTokenIfNecessary() {
  // syncs new JWT token with redux state 
  updateAnaltyicsProviderWithNewToke(token)
}
```

The problem is I want the analytics code to periodically request a token refresh. In order to do this I want to pass in a callback that lets the Analytics code dispatch an action to trigger the refreshTokenIfNesscary() saga.

```
   function* setupAnalyticsProvider(response: any): any {
         // get some global session data  
         setupAnalytics(data) 
         setAnaltyicsRefreshCallback(() => {
            // Dispatch action 
        })
    }
```

Is there anyway to hook into the store dispatch method, or maybe using Saga-Channels to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For any periodic execution of your analytic code ,you would have to create a callback for it to flow ,if the refactor is the problem use Event channel sockets for emit ,on and yield your callbacks.

Comment: Yah that makes sense thank you. Was wondering if there was an easier way but this seems to be simplest